# How can I add in the missing days of the week in a dataframe before plotting as a bar chart?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which is a summary of different trips performed by a vessel:

```
                     start_time duration_idle duration_at_power
Trip 1  2021-02-01 13:55:35.331      0.828611          1.162222
Trip 2  2021-02-02 07:25:41.574      0.516389          0.927778
Trip 3  2021-02-02 09:46:10.573      0.095278            0.1825
Trip 4  2021-02-02 12:45:15.416      0.933611          0.877778
Trip 5  2021-02-02 15:24:45.416      0.298056          1.020833
Trip 6  2021-02-03 07:06:17.665      2.035278          3.190278
Trip 7  2021-02-03 13:15:07.665      0.318611          0.212778
Trip 9  2021-02-04 09:48:59.569      1.025278            0.8325
Trip 10 2021-02-04 14:15:34.569        0.8175          2.068333
Trip 11 2021-02-04 18:21:46.570      0.152778          0.096944
Trip 12 2021-02-05 08:32:26.164      0.292778          1.319722
Trip 13 2021-02-07 08:23:36.930          0.66          0.790556
Trip 14 2021-02-08 07:11:55.395      0.513611          1.662778
Trip 16 2021-02-10 14:48:29.846      0.348056          0.761111
Trip 17 2021-02-12 08:33:30.031      0.737222          1.628611
Trip 18 2021-02-12 13:23:56.530      0.286944          0.443056
Trip 19 2021-02-12 18:33:42.529      0.423611          1.516667
Trip 21 2021-02-15 10:58:31.113      0.667222          0.339444
Trip 23 2021-02-16 11:50:25.271        1.3925          1.330278
Trip 26 2021-02-19 11:47:22.429         0.305          0.551667
Trip 27 2021-02-19 13:30:03.428      0.385833          0.393889
Trip 28 2021-02-19 20:21:59.429      0.304722          1.805556
Trip 29 2021-02-20 08:30:38.109      0.512222          0.250833
Trip 30 2021-02-20 10:01:39.128      0.656389          1.345278
Trip 32 2021-02-22 06:20:30.073      1.192222          1.393333
Trip 33 2021-02-22 10:06:27.074      0.127778          0.155556
Trip 34 2021-02-22 12:57:33.073      0.530278          0.452778
Trip 35 2021-02-23 06:59:40.838      0.369722          1.243333
Trip 36 2021-02-23 10:09:26.837      0.384167          1.151667
Trip 37 2021-02-24 07:57:10.042      1.488056          2.157778
Trip 38 2021-02-24 13:41:00.380      0.328333          0.536944
Trip 39 2021-02-24 16:06:28.380      0.421944          0.880556
Trip 40 2021-02-25 07:32:55.790      0.431944          1.528889
Trip 41 2021-02-25 10:38:04.792      0.189444          0.087778
Trip 42 2021-02-25 11:08:34.791      0.320556              0.05
Trip 43 2021-02-25 13:27:26.793      0.376389          0.796111
Trip 44 2021-02-25 15:38:56.790           0.2          0.222778
Trip 45 2021-02-26 07:39:54.299      0.890278            0.8975
Trip 46 2021-02-26 10:17:45.878      0.271944          0.806389
```

Which I am splitting into different weeks, and then plotting the sum of the durations in a given day as a a bar chart:

```
def plot_weeks(df):
    weeks = df.groupby(df["start_time"].dt.week)
    for _, week in weeks:
        week.groupby(week["start_time"].dt.day)[["duration_idle", "duration_at_power"]].sum().plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

Which generates dataframes like:

Week 1:

```
            duration_idle  duration_at_power
start_time                                  
1                0.828611           1.162222
2                1.843333           3.008889
3                2.353889           3.403056
4                1.995556           2.997778
5                0.292778           1.319722
7                0.660000           0.790556
```

Week 2:

```
            duration_idle  duration_at_power
start_time                                  
8                0.513611           1.662778
10               0.348056           0.761111
12               1.447778           3.588333
```

Which results in plots like:

Week 1:

[image: Week 1]

Week 2:

[image: Week 2]

However I am looking to make it so that it always plots 7 days in the weekly plot, like the first week. When there are days without any trips, how can I automatically add a row in the dataframe when there is a day with no data?

As a starting point I was thinking it may be useful for the groupby function to set the index as a datetime of the day, rather than just the day number, however I am also not sure how to do that.

Comment: I see your dataframe but not your code for making the graph. I assume you're using matplotlib? I think this might be something you have to do manually when making the graph. You can specify the x values for any matplotlib graph, so just put seven x slots and put zeroes for each other entry

Comment: @QuinnFreedman the .plot.bar(stacked=True) code creates the bar charts, built into Pandas (using matplotlib in the backend). However, I will give that a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proceed as follows:

1. Resample by *Day* frequency on *start_time* and sum:

   ```
   wrk = df.resample('D', on='start_time').sum()
   ```
2. Note that *resample* adds "zero rows" for any missing days **within**
   the source period, but can not do it **after** the final date.
   So, in order to have the last plot with **7** days, add such "zero rows",
   to top up the last week, possibly "not completed" in the source data:

   ```
   dayNo = wrk.index.size
   wrk = wrk.reindex(pd.date_range(start=wrk.index.min(),
       periods=dayNo - (dayNo % -7)), fill_value=0)
   ```
3. Add *Week* column (will be needed to group by weeks):

   ```
   wrk['Week'] = wrk.index.isocalendar().week
   ```
4. In order to have just dates in the *x* axis (without the time part),
   change the index type to *string*:

   ```
   wrk.index = wrk.index.astype(str)
   ```
5. Generate your plots:

   ```
   for week, grp in wrk.groupby('Week'):
       grp.iloc[:, :2].plot.bar(stacked=True, title=f'Week {week}')
   ```

   Note `iloc[:, :2]` to drop *Week* (the last) column.

For the first week I got:

[image]

As you can see, I added titles for each week and *x* labels are
**full** dates, instead of just day numbers.

Other weeks check on your own.

I also suggest to change column names, at least in *wrk*, to have more
"reader friendly" names in plot legends.

## Edit

I realized that there can be a need to add some "zero rows" also at the
**beginning** of *wrk* (if current month starts on other day than Monday).
To properly reindex *wrk*, even in the above case, change *Step 2* of the
above code to:

```
# Move back to Monday (if needed)
d1 = pd.offsets.Week(weekday=0).rollback(wrk.index.min())
# Move forward to Sunday (if needed)
d2 = pd.offsets.Week(weekday=6).rollforward(wrk.index.max())
wrk = wrk.reindex(pd.date_range(start=d1, end=d2), fill_value=0)
```

It is more concise and does not use *datetime* module (*Pandas* has
its own tools to deal with dates, so it is a good habit not to use
other modules dealing with date / time).

Note also that e.g. for May 2021 the expanded date range is from *'2021-04-26'*
to *'2021-06-06'*. It contains **42** days (6 full weeks), so the formula
to round the "initial" number of days (*31*) up to a multiple of 7 is in
this case wrong.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted to do. I made one altercation which was to change the start date in the date_range line to the first day of the week, on the minimum date of the index. Here is how I did it:

    start_date = wrk.index.date.min().isocalendar()
    start_week = start_date[1]
    start_year = start_date[0]
    d = str(start_year) +"-W"+str(start_week)
    resample_start = datetime.datetime.strptime(d + "-1", "%Y-W%W-%w")
    wrk = wrk.reindex(pd.date_range(start = resample_start,
                                    periods = dayNo - (dayNo % -7)), fill_value=0)

Comment: Thanks for the edit, that looks a lot cleaner than my method!